# Why are many of my tmux setup commands giving errors?

Tags: tmux

Getting loads of invalid option errors:

For example

```
.tmux.conf:36: invalid option: window-status-fg
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Many options have changed in recent versions.

Here is a guide to changes.
You will notice that `-style` gets added to all of them and then there are other changes in format for the rest of the line.

[image]

Here's the text for you to copy and paste

```
setw -g window-status-style fg=cyan    
setw -ga window-status-style bg=default
setw -ga window-status-style dim 
setw -g window-status-current-style fg=white     
setw -ga window-status-current-style bg=black
setw -ga window-status-current-style bright
set -g pane-border-style fg=green      
set -ga pane-border-style bg=black
set -g pane-active-border-style fg=white
set -ga pane-active-border-style bg=yellow
set -g message-style fg=white          
set -ga message-style bg=black
set -ga message-style bright
set-window-option -g window-status-current-style bg=black 
set-window-option -ga window-status-current-style fg=yellow 
set-window-option -ga window-status-current-style dim
```

Comment: This answer is wrong unless you add -a to the second and third commands for each option.

Comment: I didn't add the a but did not experience any issues.  Please could you expand on 'wrong', i.e. what issue would I have without the a, thanks.

Comment: Without -a each set of the same option is replacing the previous rather than adding to it.

Comment: Updated with the -a  Didn't see any change by updated anyway

Comment: See also: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1688